# why it is not navigating into another page in angular js

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I am try to navigate in another component using `this.router.navigate` with a `id` but it not giving error as well as it is not navigating ..

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/E6HCvkksFPt4mK4lN6mU?p=preview

```
moveToSecond(){
    alert('----')
    this.router.navigate(['/sd',{id:'ss'}]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a desired URL, you have use below.

```
this.router.navigate(['/sd','ss']);
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BmbeEySDMA0C7G8BUYuk?p=preview)